# what is the correct way to define an argument in Haskell function

Tags: haskell, binary-tree, binary-search-tree

I'm working with binary search trees in Haskell.

Here is the code I wrote

```
data BinaryTree a = Leaf | Node (BinaryTree a) a (BinaryTree a)
 deriving (Show, Eq)
  insert :: (Ord a, Eq a) => a -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a
  insert e (Leaf)= (Node Leaf e Leaf)
  insert e (Node n1 a n2) 
      | e<a=(Node (insert e n1) a n2)
      | otherwise = (Node n1 a (insert e n2))
```

So basically this piece of code inserts the element in the BST and it works fine if the second argument is locked inside the parentheses (e.g `insert 5 (Node Leaf 2 Leaf)`),but in order to obtain what I want, I need my program to work in both cases, when the second argument in inside parentheses and when it isn't (e.g. `insert 5 Node Leaf 2 Leaf`) 
Can you advise something on how this code can be rewritten in order to obtain what is described above

Comment: There are some extra parentheses in your code, here is what it looks like cleaned up: http://pastebin.com/vpNKvDW7

Comment: I don't think you actually _need_ to call `insert 5 Node Leaf 2 Leaf` without parentheses. This looks as a XY problem to me -- as if you needed something completely different, but only mentioned parentheses. What are you actually trying to achieve with that?

Answer (score 6):

`insert 5 Node Leaf 2 Leaf` calls the `insert` function with 5 arguments, not two. If you want this to work, the only way is to define `insert` to take 5 arguments.

There's no way to make both `insert 5 Node Leaf 2 Leaf` and `insert 5 (Node Leaf 2 Leaf)` work nor is there a way to make the 5-argument version work with smaller or larger trees, so there'd be very little point to it.

If you want to avoid parentheses, you could just use `$` instead:

```
insert 5 $ Node Leaf 2 Leaf
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a feeling what you want is impossible. With parenthesis, insert has a type `insert::a -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a` (Constraints elided for clarity). However, without parenthesis the type would be: `insert::a -> (BinaryTree a -> a -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a) -> BinaryTree a -> a -> BinaryTree a -> BinaryTree a`

To get you closer, however, there's a few options I can suggest.

First, use the low-precedence application operator `$`

```
insert 5 $ Node Leaf 2 Leaf
```

Second, you might bind the new sub-tree by using a `let`, or `where` clause

```
let t = Node Leaf 2 Leaf
in  insert 5 t
```

or

```
insert 5 t
  where t = Node Leaf 2 Leaf
```

Third, use a one argument constructor, but this again needs parentheses or `$`.

```
node n = Node Leaf n Leaf
--One of the following
insert 5 . node $ 2
(insert 5 . node) 2
insert 5 (node 2)
```